# "Incorrect number of dimension" after splitting a dataframe for running a loop

Tags: r, loops, split

I'm stuck with a script since a few hours now and I'm unable to solve the problem. Here's my goal: I have a huge data set of coordinates and elevation for 143 quadrats (containing between 40 to 50 observations within a quadrat). I would like to extract the mean slope and aspect for each quadrat. I know how to proceed from the GIS point of view, my script runs perfectly for the entire plot.

I begin by splitting the dataset into 143 dataframes. Then I run a loop for each quadrat and I always get the same error message: "Error in split[i, 2:3]: incorrect number of dimensions". The problem certainly comes from the way I'm writing the loop or from the way I'm using "[ ]" "[[ ]]".

Anyone has an idea of where the problem is?
Thanks a lot!

```
data = read.table("Coordinates_elevation.txt", sep = "\t")
quad = data[,1]
X = data[,2]
Y = data[,3]
Z = data[,4]

results = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(split), ncol = 3))
row.names(results) = names(split)
colnames(results) <- c('Elevation', 'Slope', 'Aspect')

data = matrix(c(quad,X,Y,Z),  ncol=4,  byrow=FALSE)
data=as.data.frame(data)
e = extent(data[,2:3])
r=raster(e, ncol=33, nrow=6, crs = CRS("+init=epsg:31300"))

split = split(data, quad)

for (i in 1:length(split)){
  x = rasterize(split[i,2:3], r, split[i,4], fun=mean)
  slope_asp=terrain(x, opt=c('slope', 'aspect'), unit='degrees',neighbors=8)
  slope = slope_asp$slope[[i]]
  results[i,2] = slope
  aspect=slope_asp$aspect[[i]]
  results[i,3] = aspect
  elevation = split[i,4]
  results[i,1]=elevation
}
```

Error in split[i, 2:3] : incorrect number of dimensions

```
write.table(results, "results_slopeaspect.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Hard to tell without some data, but what does it say if you run `dim(split)`? In your for loop, `length(split)` will give you the number of columns if split is a dataframe, and I suspect you want to loop through rows? If so try `nrow()`

Comment: dim(split) gives me NULL. Length(split) gives me 143 which is my number of quadrats. nrow(data) gives me 9243 which is my total number of observations and nrow(split$`1`) for example gives me 53 which is well my number of observations in the first quadrat...

Comment: OK so the problem then is that split is a list, so your syntax is off. If I am correct in assuming that when you write `split[i, 2:3]` what you want are the second and third columns of the `i`th quadrat then the syntax would be `split[[i]][,2:3]` and this would return all observations of the second and third columns in the `i'`th quadrat. The reason it is not working is because at the moment you are subsetting by row and column an object that does not have these dimensions (hence `dim(split)` is NULL).